# Combing CSV files powershell

Tags: variables, powershell, csv

So here is the backstory, I am attempting to validate data in several different ways. I've queried a database and exported that data to a csv.

Then using powershell I run the following commands

```
$staleDates = Import-Csv DataAudit.csv | Where-Object { $_.asOfDate -ne "" } | Foreach-Object { $_.AsOfDate = $_.AsOfDate -as [datetime]; $_ } | Where-Object {$_.asOfDate -lt $measuredDate}

$nullDates = Import-Csv DataAudit.csv | Where-Object {$_.asOfDate -eq ""}

$percentTooLarge = Import-Csv DataAudit.csv | Foreach-Object { $_.SumHoldingPercent = $_.SumHoldingPercent -as [float]; $_ } | Where-Object { $_.SumHoldingPercent -gt 100 }

$percentTooSmall = Import-Csv DataAudit.csv | Where-Object {$_.SumHoldingPercent -ne "" } | Foreach-Object { $_.SumHoldingPercent = $_.SumHoldingPercent -as [float]; $_ } | Where-Object {$_.SumHoldingPercent -lt 99.99999 }
```

Is there a way that I can combine the results from these 4 variables into a single csv that I can then email out as a report of the bad data?

also, I am using Powershell v1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
$badData = Import-Csv DataAudit.csv | Where-Object { $_.asOfDate -ne "" } | Foreach-Object { $_.AsOfDate = $_.AsOfDate -as [datetime]; $_ } | Where-Object {$_.asOfDate -lt $measuredDate}
$badData += Import-Csv DataAudit.csv | Where-Object {$_.asOfDate -eq ""}
$badData += Import-Csv DataAudit.csv | Foreach-Object { $_.SumHoldingPercent = $_.SumHoldingPercent -as [float]; $_ } | Where-Object { $_.SumHoldingPercent -gt 100 }
$badData += Import-Csv DataAudit.csv | Where-Object {$_.SumHoldingPercent -ne "" } | Foreach-Object { $_.SumHoldingPercent = $_.SumHoldingPercent -as [float]; $_ } | Where-Object {$_.SumHoldingPercent -lt 99.99999 }

$badData | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path allBadData.csv
```

Comment: I am currently getting the error of "Export-CSV : Cannot bind argument to parament 'inputobject' because it is null'. Which makes sense as this is used to specifically target null values. How could I fix this?

Comment: This is saying that $badData doesn't have a value.  If you're saying that's expected, it might be good to catch that.

If ($badData -eq $null){Write-Host No Bad Data. Woohoo.}
Else {$badData | Export-Csv ....}